# Apache spark Cluster design cluster advice

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to gain some experience using Apache Spark and have managed to get access to some vm's that I was hoping I could use to deploy a spark cluster to mine some data I'm not authorised to deploy to IAAS or PAAS

> 20 ubuntu 14.04 64Bit vms with 6GB ram, 2 vCPUs, 6 GB RAM, 20 HDD
>   local each  The 20 vm's have access to 500 GB shared storage

**Update: Shared Storage is NFS mount from a NAS appliance**

Details from /proc/mounts file

> RemoteNASBox /mnt/mySharedStorage
>   rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=*[192IPaddress]*,mountvers=3,mountport=1234,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=*[192IPaddress]* 0 0

While its only small potatoes when it comes to clusters I'd love to be able to setup a spark cluster (possibly with yarn or mesos) for python based data analysis.

My question is

**What would the recommended configuration for 20 vms so I make use of the shared storage?**